# How to cut pixel size rectangle from GeoTIFF image with GDAL Python

Tags: python, gdal

I have GeoTIFF image with EPSG "4326" and longitude, latitude of a point in the image.

I need to cut a sub-image from the original image around the point (lng,lat) with the size of 128x128 pixels.